# How to show the next image in gallery by clicking a button?

Tags: android, gallery

I want to make "next and previous buttons" to navigate between images in gallery. 
I already made an image-view and set its view with one of gallery's images then I want if I click on next button the next image in gallery to be shown.
Is there any code to do that?

Comment: This is the question neither the problem. Show your code what you have done and what problems/exceptions you are facing. These type of questions can be solved using google.com

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain هل تتحدث العربية ؟؟

Comment: @mohammad لا، أنا لا أتكلم العربية

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain انا اريد ان اعرض صورة من معرض الصور واريد ان انشئ زر التالي وعند الضغط عليه يقوم بعرض الصورة التالية في معرض الصور .. اريد الكود البرمجي لهذا الزر .. هذا هو سؤالي .. هل لديك فكرة عن الكود الذي اريده ؟؟

Answer (score 0):

Collect all your images in int array.
i.e. `private int imgArray[] = { R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2};`
and after that set image to image-view on prev and next button click
i.e. `imgView.setImageResource(imgArray[i]);`

EDIT:-
If you want get images from gallery then collect all images in File format
i.e. `String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment
          .getExternalStorageDirectory()
          .getAbsolutePath();`

```
    String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/test/";

    File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);

    File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();`
```

and after that add one by one image in your simple array-list

```
ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();
 for (File file : files){
     itemList.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

then use itemList.

Comment: So how to get all the gallery images and put it into array ??